# no back button on navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have a view controller that has a button on it.  When the button is clicked it goes to the navigation controller which goes to another view controller.  When I click on the button It goes to the second view controller but there is no back button.  Is this because I embedded the navigation controller only on the second view and not both? I only want the navigation bar on the second view controller

Comment: How are you getting to the second view controller that you want to have a navigation bar?

Comment: I think you're not pushing the viewcontroller to the navigationcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that only the second view controller should have a navigation bar. This means that your approach is correct: wrap the second view controller into a navigation controller and *present the navigation controller modally*.

Now the second view controller is the *top* view controller on the navigation stack. That means, there is no "back" button because you are already on the top!

The solution is to implement your own "Cancel" button that dismisses the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it like the picture:

[image]

Comment: image only or link only answer are less appreciated.